# How to extract an specified object from an array?

Tags: javascript

I try to extract jobs objects from each object but seem that something is not working nor console.log. If I change `result` from console.log with `response` and comment the line above I will receive the following document

```
[13:01:53] Array [
[13:01:53]   Object {
[13:01:53]     "_id": "5b276024009b5409f30703ef",
[13:01:53]     "jobs": Array [
[13:01:53]       Object {
[13:01:53]         "_id": "5b276afd8d05600a78e91fea",
[13:01:53]         "description": "",
[13:01:53]         "location": Array [
[13:01:53]           Object {
[13:01:53]             "_id": "5b276afd8d05600a78e91feb",
[13:01:53]           },
[13:01:53]         ],
[13:01:53]         "postDate": "2018-06-18T08:18:16.893Z",
[13:01:53]       },
[13:01:53]       Object {
[13:01:53]         "_id": "5b276c35bab2220ae8ec8859",
[13:01:53]         "description": "",
[13:01:53]         "location": Array [
[13:01:53]           Object {
[13:01:53]             "_id": "5b276c35bab2220ae8ec885a",
[13:01:53]           },
[13:01:53]         ],
[13:01:53]         "postDate": "2018-06-18T08:18:16.893Z",
[13:01:53]       },
[13:01:53]     ],
[13:01:53]   },
[13:01:53]   Object {
[13:01:53]     "_id": "5b277edbcb87d00c30a3a40f",
[13:01:53]     "jobs": Array [],
[13:01:53]   },
[13:01:53] ]
```

Here is my function where I try to achieve this

```
export function getAllJobs(dispatch, getState) {
  const state = getState();
  const { token } = state.auth;
  return axios.get(JOBS_ALL_URL, {
    headers: { authorization: token }
  }).then((response) => {
    const { result } = response.map(obj => obj.jobs);
    console.log(result)
    dispatch(setJobs(result));
  }).catch((err) => {
    dispatch(console.log("Couldn't get jobs."));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood, but I think the problem is that `jobs` is an array, not an object, so this should work:

```
var result = [];

response.map(o=>{
result.push(o.jobs);
   });

   console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. It is actually response.data.map ( ... )